# receive sms only in android app

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I want to write an app that receives sms but I also want the received sms to not appear in the built-in messaging app. Can I do it?

Secondly, I want to save received sms in my app, how can I do it?

Comment: I see a bunch of similar questions in the Related section. Please do some research and come back when you have actually tried something.

Comment: Have a look at this. http://www.apriorit.com/our-company/dev-blog/227-handle-sms-on-android